# tikz-cd: anchoring and shifting arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I would like to ask you what is the best method to shift and anchor arrows in `tikz-cd` package. To be more specific, by means of the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]

\mathbf{DV}\ni \mathfrak{M}_1 \arrow[d, "i" left, ->,shift right, start anchor={-40}, end anchor={40}] \arrow[d, "i^{-1}", <-,shift left,start anchor={-40}, end anchor={40}] \\
\mathbf{DV}\ni \mathfrak{M}_2

\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I obtained the following diagram:

[image]

As you can see the arrows on the left are slightly slanted. I would like the arrows to be centered below and above `\mathfrak{M}_1` and `\mathfrak{M}_2`. Could you please give me a hint how to handle this? The second question concerns alignment of `i` and  `i^{-1}`. Is there any internal `tikz-cd` tool which allows me to align them with respect to their bottoms?

Comment: Try loading mathtools and wrap `DC\ni` in `\mathllap`

Comment: Plus I don't see that they are slanted

Comment: They are, very little bit. The tail comes from the point on the left of M while the head goes to the point located on the letter.

Comment: @MadHatter Please always try to reduce your problem to the real core. That makes it much easier for us to reproduce the problem and to fix the culprit part, not to search it. I added a real MWE to your post. Please roll back, if you do not want that. But I think, it shows the problem you are facing much better.

Comment: Or even shorter: `\begin{tikzcd}
 AAAAA \arrow[d, start anchor={-40}, end anchor={40}] \\
 AAAAA
\end{tikzcd}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Your proposal was not exactly my question, but I have simplified mine.

Comment: Well, your main question was about shifting and anchoring and you suggest that the boxes might have different size. They don't. If my short example above does not exactly show your issue, I don't understand what you are asking, to be honest.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer has shown me how to get rid of that 40° degree issue. Please see my updated answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use just the `shift` options without the anchors:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
  \mathbf{DV}\ni \mathfrak{M}_1
  \arrow[d, "i" left, ->,shift left=5]
  \arrow[d, "i^{-1}", <-,shift left=7] \\
  \mathbf{DV}\ni \mathfrak{M}_2
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

To make the positioning of the `i` and `i^{-1}` uniform you can use a `\mathstrut`, which is `\vphantom(` or perhaps more appropriately a `\vphantom1` on the first `i`:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
  \mathbf{DV}\ni \mathfrak{M}_1
  \arrow[d, "i^{\vphantom1}" left, ->,shift left=5]
  \arrow[d, "i^{-1}", <-,shift left=7] \\
  \mathbf{DV}\ni \mathfrak{M}_2
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The two boxes you have are having the same size. Therefore I would do another question on why the anchoring at 40° does not work. (see my comments above)

In any case you seem to treat the `\mathbf{DV}` as something which does not really belong to the main part which is `\mathfrak{M}_1`. If you want to separate that, the arrows should be situated centred below that main symbol in order to stay consistent. I think it would make syntactical sense to split the two terms into two nodes. Please see my example below. No need for anchors though.

I have changed the arrows a bit in order to safe typing. I also have introduced the possibility to `\smash` a character. I prefer the `\vphantom` shown by Mr. Swann, but you may chose.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{%
    symbol/.style={%
        draw=none,
        every to/.append style={%
            edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$#1$}}
            }
        }
    }
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
    \mathbf{DV}\arrow[symbol=\ni]{r} &[-3em] \mathfrak{M}_1 \arrow[shift left]{d}{i} \\
    \mathbf{DV}\arrow[symbol=\ni]{r} & \mathfrak{M}_2 \arrow[shift left]{u}{i^{\smash{-1}}}
\end{tikzcd}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to stick to your anchors given by degree values, you will have to tell `tikz-cd` to treat every node as a rectangle. This will fix the issue you have seen here.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzcd}[%
        ,row sep=large
        ,column sep=large
        ,cells={shape=rectangle}
        ]
        \mathbf{DV}\ni \mathfrak{M}_1 \arrow[shift left, start anchor=-40, end anchor=40]{d}{i} \\
        \mathbf{DV}\ni \mathfrak{M}_2 \arrow[shift left, start anchor=40, end anchor=-40]{u}{i^{\smash{-1}}}
    \end{tikzcd}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I may have misunderstood your edit to my answer - not sure about it. Anyway, thanks a lot for the above. This will let me do anything I need to do now in my diagrams.

Comment: @MadHatter Glad to hear that. You are welcome.

Comment: Let me ask you one more question - why do you prefer <code>\vphantom<\code> to <code>\smash<\code>?

Comment: @MadHatter I think that smashed version a bit too close to the upper arrow head. I tend to center the bigger label (here: `i^{-1}`) in respect to the arrow. In my code, I have centered just the `i` as I have smashed the superscript. But this is really cosmetic, just compare it yourself. Another reason is that the smash is ugly for horizontal arrows with labels below. Obviously, one should treat any case, one by one, but I like to be consistent and got used to the phantom approach.

Comment: OK, got it. I will experiment with my diagrams. Thanks!